# Is generating/viewing a report a valid usecase?

Tags: uml, use-case

If we take "***cancel order***" use-case, the user might have to view all the orders before canceling a particular one from the list of orders. As i see, "View order" is the pre-condition for the "***cancel order***" use-case.

And also there can be other use-cases like **view / generate** lists or reports. Are these valid in a use-case diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the user might have to view all the orders before canceling... "View order" is the pre-condition for the "cancel order" use-case.

In your situation it is not a precondition. It is a step in "Cancel order" user goal use case. And this step could be expanded (or kept as a single step depending on what level you are describing) into extend (if user *might* view) or include (if user *must* view) "View order" use case.

> other use-cases like view / generate lists or reports. Are these valid in a use-case diagram?

Most likely you are facing (note titles of the use cases):

- User goal use case like `Accountant orders [payments/agents/etc.] report` with step `System generates [payments/agents/etc.] report`. (Keep in mind that user never comes to system with intention "and now I want to *generate* a report", user needs the report for some higher goal).
- Subfunction use case `System generates [payments/agents/etc.] report`.

If your diagram is all about user goal use cases and higher in the hierarchy - do not sacrifice readability with subfunction ones. Better create separate diagrams for specific business processes or application domains.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a use case shows a single added value a system under consideration returns to an actor. Now, what is an added value? Sometimes it depends. Especially when you deal with CRUD, discussions tend to finally split hairs. So whether it's better to show separate UCs for "create/read/update/delete X" or to summarize them in a single "manage X" absolutely depends on the importance of the single CRUD parts. If viewing is a very important part since it's done most of the time and the CUD is definitely apart of it, they should be split. Where you do all the CRUD operations with more or less the same intensity you're better off with a single UC.

Answer (score 1):

Generate reports - yes. Even more, it is a very good practice to distinquish reports for not only different sorts of users, but for supporters of the SW, too.

But don't forget, that you should also tell reports on the high level, that can be done on demand or automatically, and that contain some concentrated info, from reports in the sense of DB generating SQL reports. You can write use cases for different abstraction levels. And the first reports are OK for the human-oriented use case, whereas DB reports are OK for the more concrete-level usecases. These last ones are used not so often.

So, we can imagine a table:

```
                           high level                  low level
Users                      useful/usual                The reports themselves are not useful
Support/lisense team       useful/not so usual         useful/usual
```

Here you have usefulness of such use case elements as reports and how often such use cases are used.